# One of the previous fields is not constant over group level of this field

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

My report shows customers who have ordered three times in the last five weeks with no outstanding orders, if the value outstanding is less than our minimum order.

Currently it selects customer code, name, order docdate, and doctotals for everything in the last 35 days. My formula concatenates the orderdate and customer name for a distinctcount. This reports if there have been enough orders in that time period.

I group by concatenation and 'run number' (which truck a customer usually goes on) and a Select Case defines what goes out on what working day. The following Switch statement seems to be where the issue is:

```
Switch
(DistinctCount ({@Concat code and date}, {ORDR.CardCode}) <=2,0,
{#RTotal0} > 250, 0,
True, 1);
```

This determines if someone has two or fewer orders over the report period, or if they have outstanding orders more than a value of £250. If those aren't met, it defaults to a usable value of '1'.

When I try to run an alert or record selection on this switch (in group headings) it doesn't appear in the list of fields that can be selected in either option. When I manually put it into the fields, I get the message:

> One of the previous fields is not constant over group level of this field

The closest question I've found is [being unable to summarize](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/117306-crystal-reports-won-t-summarize-or-running-total-my-formula-field) but I've had no success. How can I work around this?

EDITNOTE - See below for new downloadable.

EDITNOTE 2 - Thanks for the interest, Siva.  The basic premise is as above.  We send out trucks delivering on specific days of the week.  I have the code on a separate form to enable that and can import - it's a bit of frippery I can add later.

The rules for this report are that if a customer has three or more orders in the last five weeks, or an order in that's less than 250 on combined doctotals, then we need to contact them to see if they want an order or to make the order up to minimum value.

Since our customers can place several orders for the same run, I had to use the concatenation formula (docdate and customer number) to note how many deliveries they had in the last 35 days via distinctcount and work out if they qualify from that.

I have a running total on the grouping based on open orders to count those to see if they qualify against the minimum order value.

A simplified version of the file is [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnJ-bWv68TrOgycqBrdBIAdTRU4K). I've taken out a few things I tried from various sources.  When I try an alert or sorting based on the 'Valid to Call Via Switch' it doesn't present the formula as one I can select, and when I manually put it in it gives the warning "One of the previous fields is not constant over group level of this field".

All assistance appreciated :)

Comment: remove group2 and try running the report, if doesn't work explain exact requirement, we can try for different solution

Comment: Thanks, Siva.  That didn't change anything, and made some other counts not work right, oddly enough.  I'll edit the main question for details.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload your Crystal Report so we can take a look?

It's a bit hard to follow what's going on. Are you trying to create a Filter over your already existing "Grouping" formula and it's not letting you?

EDIT: Looking at your post again, it might be a better solution to try to offload some of the grouping/filtering logic to your query. Sometimes having to do this in Crystal can add unnecessary complexity to your report logic.

Regardless, post your CR and I'll take a look.

EDIT 2:
I think the problem is due to the evaluation time of the formula with the switch statement. Because of the Running Total, it forces this formula to run "WhilePrintingRecords" which is the last of the evaluation times. Because of this I think it won't let you setup a Record Selection filter.

My recommendation is that you offload that RT calculation to a query, in other words setup a "OpenDocTotal" field in your Order query (change from your ORDR table to a query that brings back whatever ORDR info you need plus this new field) that returns 0 when the DocStatus is closed and the DocTotal when the DocStatus is open. You could then try to use a regular Summary in your formula based on this field. If that doesn't work, then you should try to just group all of your data in your query and with that approach it will simplify the Crystal logic considerably.

Comment: It's either a filter or an alert based on the result of a formula.  When I try to create the alert or filter via the GUI, it doesn't offer the field as one I can use.  When I type it in manually, it gives the warning above.  I'll see what I can do to upload it, but there are some fields unique to my place's operation and thus it won't work with standard SAP B1.  Cheers for the answer thus far :)

Comment: OK, looks like I need to remember (reset) my password for Live to upload a file to attach here.  May be trying this from home tonight as I don't have resources here.

Comment: Thanks for EDIT2.  However, the whiteprintingrecords items are ones I added recently as per the link in the original description.  Taking them out and trying to evaluate on the "@valid to call switch" field is where I ran into the issue, and the claims on that link were that it would solve it - the same issue arose, sadly.

Comment: That sucks. Looks like an obscure Crystal formula issue. I think your best bet is to re-organize the report queries like I suggested. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for trying :)